# Getting Rack mounted path in Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

Suppose I have the following `config.ru` file

```
require './status.rb'

map "/status" do
  run Sinatra::Application
end
```

and the `status.rb` is a simple

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Some status here...'
end
```

I'd like to know where the Sinatra application is mounted inside `status.rb` (for example to provide proper paths to resources). Is there a way of retrieving that information from Rack?

Answer (score 3):

To get where the app is mounted you can use [`request.script_name`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object).

```
get '/' do
  p request.script_name # will print "/status"
  'Some status here...'
end
```

If you’re generating urls for resources, you might want to look at the [`url` method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Generating%20URLs) instead. That will take into account things like proxies as well as where the app is mounted:

```
get '/' do
  p url('foo') # will print "http://localhost:9292/status/foo"
  'Some status here...'
end
```